# Can't upgrade or install software. Get a strange error that says it failed to fetch data from a very sketchy website

Tags: raspbian, linux, software-installation, sudo

When running the commands:

- sudo apt-get upgrade
- sudo apt install xscreensaver

I get the error "Failed to fetch https://113store.cr/es/ Writing more data than expected (131072 > 121282)" at the end of the installation. Why would running those commands attempt to fetch data from that website? I am extremely confused. Thanks.

Comment: Mirror repository? You ran / installed a program that changed your apt list? Would be helpful if you post the full message (add it to your question). Makes it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: Have you had your RPi open to the internet without an adequate firewall? Has something compromised your system security. First thing I'd do is get that RPi off the 'net. Second thing I'd do is build a new SDCard with RaspiOS Buster 32. Third thing I'd do is learn about firewalling and hardening security before opening it to the 'net again.

Comment: aren't you supposed to do an apt-get update first?

Comment: I have the same issue - fresh install today of Raspian Lite - connected behind a firewall. Error occurs when trying to install nectat. apt-get update and apt-get upgrade performed also.

Comment: So that's 3 people with the same problem ... perhaps raspberry pi repos have been compromised ...

Comment: I also have the same issue. Trying to install Pi-hole on a brand new Raspberry Pi 4, but getting the error `Get:1 http://raspbian-us.ngc292.space/raspbian buster/main armhf netcat all 1.10-41.1 [9,034 B]
Err:1 http://raspbian-us.ngc292.space/raspbian buster/main armhf netcat all 1.10-41.1
  File has unexpected size (32768 != 9034). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 198.211.116.210 443]
E: Failed to fetch https://113store.cr/es/  File has unexpected size (32768 != 9034). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 198.211.116.210 443]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem today.  I changed the mirror in sources.list to another mirror from this list:  https://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianMirrors  and it worked fine.

Prior to this, I was using " http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/  " which appears to be the root cause of the problem.

And just to clarify, the problem occurs in my case on a clean system.  I did the apt-get upgrade first, but with the raspbian mirror in sources.list, it is fetching from the 113store website mentioned in the question.

Comment: Should we not trust anything hosted on raspberrypi.org at the moment?

Comment: It should be OK now. The RPF folks have removed that Raspbian Repo so the mirror director should pick some other mirror for you.